# how do I add a object to another object

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to add the object Nicaragua to the list of objects in the hammondmines variable in JavaScript.  How would I do that? I am using the object.assign method, I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Example

```
Const Hamondmines = {
{
  buensAires: {
    depth: '400 meters',
    annualBudget: 1000000,
    specimens: [ 'Dilophosaurus', 'Brachiosaurus' ]
  },
  
mexico: {
    depth: '350 meters',
    annualBudget: 900000,
    specimens: [ 'Gallimimus', 'Parasaurolophus' ]
  },
 
   nicaragua: {
      depth: '200 meters',
      annualBudget: 1500000,
      specimens: [
        'Tyrannosaurus Rex',
        'Stegosaurous',
        'Triceratops',
        'Velociraptor',
      ],
    };
```

This is the codes that I started with and the things that I did that did not work.

```
  const nicaragua = {
      depth: '200 meters',
      annualBudget: 1500000,
      specimens: [
        'Tyrannosaurus Rex',
        'Stegosaurous',
        'Triceratops',
        'Velociraptor',
      ],
    };


const hammondsMines = {
  buenosAires: {
    depth: '400 meters',
    annualBudget: 1000000,
    specimens: ['Dilophosaurus', 'Brachiosaurus'],
  },
  mexico: {
    depth: '350 meters',
    annualBudget: 900000,
    specimens: ['Gallimimus', 'Parasaurolophus'],
  },
};
```

```
Object.assign(hammondsMines,nicaragua)

console.log(hammondsMines)
```

Comment: thanks for the edit PM

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
 const nicaragua = {
      depth: '200 meters',
      annualBudget: 1500000,
      specimens: [
        'Tyrannosaurus Rex',
        'Stegosaurous',
        'Triceratops',
        'Velociraptor',
      ],
    };


const hammondsMines = {
  buenosAires: {
    depth: '400 meters',
    annualBudget: 1000000,
    specimens: ['Dilophosaurus', 'Brachiosaurus'],
  },
  mexico: {
    depth: '350 meters',
    annualBudget: 900000,
    specimens: ['Gallimimus', 'Parasaurolophus'],
  },
};

console.log("before assigning")
console.log(hammondsMines)

console.log("after assigning")
hammondsMines.nicaragua = nicaragua
console.log(hammondsMines)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const nicaragua = {
  nicaragua: {
    depth: '200 meters',
    annualBudget: 1500000,
    specimens: [
      'Tyrannosaurus Rex',
      'Stegosaurous',
      'Triceratops',
      'Velociraptor',
    ],
   }
};


const hammondsMines = {
  buenosAires: {
    depth: '400 meters',
    annualBudget: 1000000,
    specimens: ['Dilophosaurus', 'Brachiosaurus'],
  },
  mexico: {
    depth: '350 meters',
    annualBudget: 900000,
    specimens: ['Gallimimus', 'Parasaurolophus'],
  },
};

Object.assign(hammondsMines,nicaragua)
```